# window.screenTop returns wrong value on multi-monitor setup

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have an external monitor plugged into my MacBook which has a larger screen than my laptop, therefore the top of my laptop screen is not the top of my external screen.

[image: Display alignment]

The display on the left is my laptop's display, and is labeled as Screen 2. On the right is my external display, and is labeled Screen 1.

When I print out `window.screenTop` on Screen 1 (external) when the browser window is maximized, I get 23 pixels. These 23 pixels are from my macOS toolbar.

[image: screenTop value on external display (screen 1)]

However, when I run `window.screenTop` on Screen 2 (laptop) in another maximized browser window, I get 303 pixels. Rather than returning the distance from the top of the browser to the top of *that* screen, it gives me the distance from the top of the browser to the top of Screen 1 (external)!

[image: screenTop value on internal display (screen 2)]

Here's a screenshot which spans both displays to show the difference:

[image: Cross-display alignment]

I would expect `screenTop` to return the distance above the browser window *for the current screen*, not across screens. This is causing issues for me because my use-case requires exact measurements of the screen in order to crop full-screen screenshots. Is there any way to fix this issue, or is there some alternative to figure out the size of `screenTop`?

`window.screen.availTop` also returns the same, incorrect value, and simply subtracting `window.screen.availHeight` from `window.screen.height` will give me the height of the macOS toolbar, but not the space above the browser. And subtracting `window.outerHeight` from `window.screen.availHeight` doesn't distinguish between space above and below the browser window.

This bug occurs on Chrome and Firefox, but not on Safari.